# Death rate after EMP

Tags: post-apocalypse, electromagnetism

At the moment, western society is heading to a economic system based on the Internet of Things, where the production and distribution of goods will be based on information collected through sensors and analysis. Also, machinery and transports are going fully electrically controlled and powered.

Assuming that in ten years this system will be completely established, how many people in the first world would starve to death in the first weeks after an Electro Magnetic Pulse that destroyed all our electronic systems? Which would be the role of less developed countries with more traditional systems?

Comment: I'm sure the government could distribute food and supplies. Even if everything was automated(or something similar) people would still want to take a walk out or have a nice stroll. And less developed countries would probably continue going about their lives as usual. The problem would arise when people in electrical cars are driving on the freeway and the EMP strikes... Another similar scenario would be solar flares which you could look into.

Comment: @sky people in electrical cars? what would be the issue?

Comment: @wannabeLearner   Super Savta addressed it. Imagine your driving at 80 km/h when the Emp strikes. Now you have no way to brake nor control your car, and on a freeway with thousands of cars traveling I'm sure you would know what happens when one crashes.

Comment: @sky brakes are not electrical thought that is why i asked. And most cars have an on-board computer that is essential for the correct function of all systems int the car. Even brakes.

Comment: @wannabeLearner indeed they are nowadays. When you put your foot on the brake, that is trasnlated to the electronic system and is processed by the onboard computer, which would be fried in my scenario.

Comment: @wannabeLearner the Emp disabled that.  I'm assuming that in a world where transport is fully electrically controlled that they have electrical brakes. Which is something in real life if you use google.

Comment: @MEPx Frictional brakes are still the most used now-days, and most i know work with oil-line. And again that is exactly what i am saying... electrical cars would not be the only one to get affected. And remember that emergency brake is always a thing (although not recommended at that speed but you could engine-brake a little first)

Comment: @Sky if you are saying that because they use regenerative brakes... not all of them have them and even the ones that have have emergency breaks, and remember that the direction system of the car would (in most cases) not be locked. And car manufacturers always have those kind of issues in mind, maybe not an emp but a power failure is something that happens often.

Comment: @wannabeLearner yes, of course, i didnt mean to say that today every car works like i say, but that a lot do and that in the future i describe in my questions all do. Also, i didnt say it, but cars will probably be computer driven in the near future; there have already been presented models that doesnt allow the human any kind of control for the sake of safety. In this scenario, a global shut down of computers an electronic systems will end with thousands of uncontrolled bullets at high speed (even slowing down).

Comment: @MEPx true still it's to expect some sort of backup no? that seems to me the main issue people point out in every presentation. Electrical failures will always happen. If people died every time one happened we wouldn't rely on that tech right?

Comment: @MEPx but i get it, and your question is mostly about starvation not cars.

Comment: @wannabeLearner That is a critical issue that is gonna create a lot of debate. But imo since problems are always going to statistically arise, I'd rather avoid the problems created by unpredictable humans, rather than machine problems that can be studied and solved. At the end, the thing is making tech less dangerous than ourselves :D

Comment: You should wait at least 24 hours before accepting an answer.  Give others a chance to post, esp. from other time zones.  Give posters a chance to react to comments.  You discouraged others from contributing by accepting the first answer so quickly, and didn’t challenge him to improve the text based on feedback.

Comment: @JDługosz I'm kinda new here, so i just used the accept as i though it was supposed to. But why would somebody be discouraged? If you have a better answer, you usually wanna say it. Anyway, how should I proceed next time?

Comment: Worldbuilding (welcome, btw!) Is a bit different from SE’s where the OP wants a practical solution to a problem and then moves on.  It’s more collaborative creativity.  In the future: wait >24 hours and then for activity to wind down.  Post comments, read comments to the question and improve it or clarify where indicated; keep up with *changes* to existing answers.

Comment: @JDługosz Ok, I will keep it in mind next time. I came here when using other StackExchange i saw one random topic suggested and I've fallen in love with all of this.

Comment: So I hope we’ll be seeing a lot more of you around here!  Jump in and try answering things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be a few different sources of casualties

1. The people who were at the time using machines which depend on electricity. This could be people in hospitals who are on life support, people driving electric cars (or any fly by wire car) or people flying. These people would die immediately.
2. The second wave of people to die would be because of the collapse of food distribution. The food distribution and manufacturing in developed countries is highly based on computers, knowing where to ship produce and in what amounts without computers (Or even long distance communication) would be impossible. This would lead to people leaving urban centers and creating pressure on the immediate country side.
3. Long term effects - without electricity the food and medical supplies we rely on for modern society would not function properly. Without the ability to work the fields using modern technology, using old methods of creating fertilizer the supply of food would decrease dramatically. This will lead to wide spread starvation and eventually to a stable level of population which is much lower than it is today. The same thing applies to modern medicine, people will start dying much more often from diseases which with today's technology are curable

In non-industrialized countries most casualties will come from the first step. As the urban centers and agricultural industry don't rely as much on technology they will be much better poised to deal with these challenges.

If we look at how non industrialized societies have improved their agriculture in recent years, by using modern methods, we can estimate how much population their agriculture can support in the long term. According to  [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricultural_productivity#/media/File:Wheat_yields_in_Least_Developed_Countries.svg), the wheat production in the least developed countries has grown by 150% in the last 50 years. If we take this as a guide this means the population will decrease by about 60% in non industrialized countries.

If we look at industrialized countries we can [see](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/fields/2212.html) that they have about an urbanization rate of about 70-80%. Given our analysis this share of the population at a minimum will starve out given this event within a few weeks.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But my real question is how big would be the descent of population. You say much lower, but could it be 25% less? 50%?

Comment: That fully depends on how non industrial the society is. For tribes living in the amazon there will be virtually no population loss. For countries which have partially modernized infrastructure there will be a bigger drop. Virtually all countries nowadays depend on some industrialized produce. If we take wheat as an example according to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agricultural_productivity#/media/File:Wheat_yields_in_Least_Developed_Countries.svg), it would seem we would lose about 60% of the population in the least developed countries

Comment: For example, the US has 318 million people. In a report of the number of people driving cars daily in 2010, the numbers came up to 210 million. If all of them die... That's around 66% of the total US population.

Comment: @Sky well, i think you give too much importance to death by car crash. Of course there will be a lot, but since all cars will stop their engines at the same time, they will slow down mostly togeher; if your freeway doesnt have curves near, you should be okay.

Comment: @Sky problem araises when yo find yourself stucked in the middle of nowhere.

Comment: @SuperSavta wow, those are big numbers. If you add it to your answer i'll mark it as accepted.

Comment: @Sky the problem with that analysis is that not all cars would be on the road at the same time, it would also highly depend on the time of day. Doing some rough calculations we can say that 81% of the US population is urban, this population would die in a matter of weeks due to overwhelming of the supply network and the ensuing starvation

Comment: People flying would *not* die immediately -- the main danger from having the electrics on an aircraft fried is actually a spiral dive in cloudy or otherwise inclement weather -- in clear weather, it's possible to land even a jumbo with no electrical help, just working flight controls, thrust, and a couple sets of Mk. I eyeballs on the flight deck.

Comment: Why do you assume that EMP would have any long term impact on availability of electricity? Most power stations are quite simple. Especially coal-based ones. Of course, regulation would be an issue, but they keep quite a lot of spare parts.

Comment: @Shalvenay Would the airplanes still be able to land without functioning air traffic control and navigational aides? I assume they can land somewhere but they would still need a proper landing strip and to know how to get there.

Comment: @Mołot that's the way I understood the question premise. It's true that you could theoretically get everything functioning again, however without cars,ships etc. it would be difficult to supply the power stations with more coal and spare parts, especially considering the organizational challenge involved. It would also be hard to fix all the machinery using only hand tools.

Comment: @SuperSavta -- in good weather, yes.  Airplanes operate out of uncontrolled airports all the time (even airliner-sized planes can do this), and pilots are taught how to navigate by reference to ground features in good weather as part of their basic training.  As to a proper place to land? That's not that hard either....

Comment: @Shalvenay A Boeing can be landed without electricity.  An Airbus is fly-by-wire, fry it's electronics and it falls from the sky.

Comment: Three categories to add to your list:  Those with medical needs for electricity that doesn't rise to the point of life support.  For example, dialysis patients.  Those stranded in hazardous circumstances.  For example, driving across Death Valley in the summer.  Those who die from the collapse of the water system.  For example, a bedroom community near here.  In summer it would not be possible to walk from there to the nearest surface water.

Comment: @LorenPechtel -- A320 has hydromechanical reversion for pitch trim and yaw (it's a bear, but it's a flight-tested bear at least)